# Java Adding 2 arrays together and return the sum of it

Tags: java

I am trying to add 2 arrays together and return the sum of it, but it doesn't produce any output. I wonder why?

```
public class MyProgram
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        new MyProgram().start();
    }

    public void start()
    {
        int[] ar1 = {3, 8, 4, 9, 5, 5, 23, 14};
        int[] ar2 = {33, 23, 41, 9, 17, 51, 23, 45};

        sumA(ar1, ar2);
    }

    private int[] sumA(int[] ar1, int[] ar2)
    {
        int[] sumArray = new int[0];

        for (int i = 0; i < ar1.length; i++)
        {
            sumArray[i] = ar1[i] + ar2[i];
        }
        return sumArray;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First, you need to instantiate the array correctly:

```
int[] sumArray = new int[ar1.length];
```

Then, if you want to see what is the result, you need to do something with it (print it maybe...):

```
System.out.println( Arrays.toString( sumA(ar1, ar2)) );
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add arrays with different lengths:

```
private static int[] sumA(int[] ar1, int[] ar2) {
    int[] sumArray = new int[Math.max(ar1.length, ar2.length)];

    for (int i = 0; i < sumArray.length; i++) {
        sumArray[i] = (i < ar1.length ? ar1[i] : 0) + (i < ar2.length ? ar2[i] : 0);
    }
    return sumArray;
}
```

If not, BobTheBuilder's answer is sufficient.

Comment: Wouldn't it be safer to use `Math.min()` instead of `Math.max()`? Using `Math.max()` may result in accessing non-existent elements in a shorter array (in case the lengths of arrays differ).

Comment: There's a check for this - "(i < ar1.length ? ar1[i] : 0)".

Answer (score 1):

Your error is here:

```
int[] sumArray = new int[0]; <---
```

you need to instantiate the array with the length of one of the two parameters.

Try this:

```
int[] sumArray = new int[ar1.length];
```

or this

```
int[] sumArray = new int[ar2.length];
```

and if you want to show results:

```
int[] sumArray = new int[ar1.length];

for (int i = 0; i < ar1.length; i++)
{
    sumArray[i] = ar1[i] + ar2[i];
    System.out.print(sumArray[i] + " ");
}
return sumArray;
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: working demo]That's because you are not writing any `system.out.println();` statements in your code. Try this code:

```
public class MyProgram
{
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    new MyProgram().start();
}

public void start()
{
    int[] ar1 = {3, 8, 4, 9, 5, 5, 23, 14};
    int[] ar2 = {33, 23, 41, 9, 17, 51, 23, 45};

    int sum[]=sumA(ar1, ar2);

    for(int i: sum)
    {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}

private int[] sumA(int[] ar1, int[] ar2)
{
    int[] sumArray = new int[8];

    for (int i = 0; i < ar1.length; i++)
    {
        sumArray[i] = ar1[i] + ar2[i];
    }
    return sumArray;
}
}
```

See the image attached.